# X-Frame-Options not working when hosted to Azure App Service

Tags: .net-core, iframe, asp.net-core-webapi, x-frame-options

**X-Frame-Options** is not working when hosted in the Azure app service, it works fine locally, When the run the application ( React + Web API ) locally and I have created an HTML page with an iFrame in it accessing the localhost URL when **X-Frame-Options** is set to **DENY** in **middleware** like below, then it works fine iFrame won't be able to load the site.

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
            await next();
        });
```

Same code when hosted and when we put the hosted **Azure app service** URL in the iFrame, then it iFrame is able to load the app, which is kind of weird.

Answer (score 0):

Which platform you use in azure app service, linux or windows ?

If you use windows, you can add `web.config` under wwwroot. If linux, you can use .htaccess file.

---

*Sample code in web.config*

```
 <system.webServer>
     <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true" >
       <customHeaders>
         <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="*" />
       </customHeaders>
     </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: This just causes me to have two conflicting headers. <clear /> also didn't clear it.