# how to add X-Frame-Options: DENY to the angular azure app server?

Tags: angular, azure-web-app-service, content-security-policy, x-frame-options, clickjacking

How and where to add the 'X-Frame-Options:DENY' to our web app service?

we are using the azure app service(linux based) and the front end is Built using Angular 13+

How and where to implement the 'X-Frame-Options:DENY' to avoid seeing the clickjacking issue for our website scan?

Note: We are not using any middleware(our frontend directly communicate with API) to add this option in web.config

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to add **`X-Frame-Options to Deny`**  in Azure Web App.

**According to this [**SO Thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70422730/x-frame-options-not-working-when-hosted-to-azure-app-service) by **Jason Pan****

As you are using **Linux OS for your angular Azure Web app** Edit your **.htaccess** file like below:-

Visit **newui** to edit your file in **Kudu**:-

**`https://webappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui/fileManager#`**

```xml
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always append X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
</IfModule>
```

[image]

If you are using **Windows OS for your angular Azure web app Edit your web.config** with below line to edit the **X-Frame_Options** like below:-

> ````xml
>      <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true" >
>        <customHeaders>
>          <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="*" />
>        </customHeaders>
>      </httpProtocol>  </system.webServer> ```
> ````

Comment: I don’t have any .htaccess file on our project directory! Can you suggest further? Thanks @siddheshDesai